# Contents of heading tags displayed differently

Tags: html, css

It's been a while (2 years?) since I've done a bigger website. I'm now developing one and as usual, I ran onto some cross-browser difficulties.

The problem I'm solving now can be seen on the picture below - I have a page with a h2 element, which displays differently in Chrome and IE 11. The element has all the properties like line-height, font-size, padding, margin and so fort specified, but still displays differently. In one browser, the text is right on the top of the element, in the other one, it is in the middle. This causes some graphical issues and I can't seem to find a way to resolve this without writing a browser-specific css definition for each browser (Firefox does something similar to and is somewhere in the middle of these two - the text is in the upper part of the element, but not on the very top of it).

The other similar elements like h1 are affected as well.

I understand this is likely related to the way these browsers handle fonts and calculate their positioning, but at the moment, this doesn't help me much. I'd be grateful for any advice you might have, since I'm probably not the first one to be solving this.

EDIT:
I won't insert the HTML code here since this affects all these elements regardless of where they appear. For an instance, the text highlighted in the page is a normal h2 with the following CSS attributes:

```
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Arial;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 27px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 20px;
text-transform: none;
width: 634px;
```

normal

has this css:

```
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
line-height: 17px;
```

[image]

Comment: The pics are useful, but the code is too small to read. Post some code in your question.

Comment: Are you using a reset.css or Normalize.css?

Comment: Post the code for the `hr` div and the css for the div and the headings inside

Comment: The old school coder in me says if you're worrying about tiny things like this, you're doing something wrong. Aka don't worry about a few pixels. Please edit your post with the CSS rules for the h2 and p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a solution. Little surprising, but makes sense.

I'm using Typekit from Adobe, which is something like google fonts. I actually found out that the cause of this text-shifting is the fact that I'm using the typekit font. When I switched to Arial, everything was fine.

I also came acrticle which describes the topic: http://blog.typekit.com/2010/09/13/updating-vertical-metrics-for-cross-platform-consistency/

The problem has to do with baseline and em boxes set wrong in the given font I used. Switching to another font which had these properties set correctly fixed my problem.

Thanks for all your help guys.